# What is 'SCORM'?

Tags: c#, asp.net, scorm2004

Could anyone tell me what exactly 'SCORM' is? 
 And if it's possible to use with .net?

Can any one give me a sample code which is already implemented in asp.net with c#

Thank you

Comment: Acronyms can be tricky. Do you mean http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scorm, for instance? The more effort you put into your questions, the better the quality and quantity of the responses. This may be part of why you've only been able to accept **one** answer out of your previous 20 questions. The StackOverflow community is *incredibly good* at answering questions that are reasonably complete and clear.

Comment: oh the SO scorn attacks again!

Comment: Yes that is what.. but i dont know how to use it.. I'm searching for the one who is already implemented

Comment: People who doesnt have any idea about SCORM will think like not useful.. hah aha

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SCORM is a standard for e-learning coursess.  It allows these courses to be defined in a standard way making it possible to transfer these course between different e-learning systems ( typically Learning management Systems) and for course content providers to sell/develop courses independently of the software used to deliver them to students.

SCORM is an XML based standard and as such any system capable of reading XML can implement code to process SCORM files.

You might want to  look at the source code of [moodle](http://moodle.org/) but SCORM is complicated

Comment: While the manifest definitions for content are XML based, the API for SCORM is a Synchronous JavaScript interface.

Answer (score 2):

[Sharable Content Object Reference Model (SCORM)](http://www.adlnet.gov/scorm/scorm-2004-4th) is an eLearning specification drafted by the [ADL](http://www.adlnet.org/) for content sharing in eLearning.  The original specification for the API was loosely based on an earlier Airline Industry CBT (Content Based Training) Committee (AICC) specification.  The original drive for SCORM was a requirement signed by President Clinton which required a certain percent of learning to be computer based training.

The server-side portion of this can be written in pretty much any server-side technology, including C# (Net).  I am unaware of any open-source implementations available in C#.

The API itself is a Synchronous JavaScript interface that is used for loading/saving various points of state.  The specification itself is very broad, and I've seen the interface actually written using a number of technologies (Java, Flash, and Synchronous XmlHttpRequest(s)).  These front end (client) interfaces can then communicate to any number of back-end technologies.

Some down sides to the synchronous nature of the API are that this can quite literally freeze UI Interaction during requests depending on the interaction.  I would suggest having a caching API, that handles its' interactions asynchronously, while mirroring the full content/interaction client side. (Exception being final commit/save action).

There is a new specification under the code name [Tin Can](http://www.adlnet.gov/resources/Tin_Can_Draft_Specification?type=technical_documentation) that is currently being worked on.  The initial test implementation was done in NodeJS with a MongoDB backend, however people in the industry were critical of the new/unfamiliar technology so recent implementations are based with an SQL backend, and a more traditional "enterprise" codebase.

Comment: I wrote a test SCORM server in early 2004 that became the base of a major aircraft engine manufacture's eLeraning site for 8 years (was displaced last year with a commercial offering), as well as several airline's for internal use.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the definition that you can read from [Wikipedia](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/SCORM), if you want to have a look at how SCORM works please give a look to [Moodle](http://moodle.org/) an e-learning open source platform where you can find some scorm sample content and see how it works